# Issue with relative path to database saving data

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, relative-path, saving-data

I am creating a bookingsystem but i ran in to a problem whith my database connections when i change from specific path to relative path for datasource, When i have a speciffic datasource it can update the database and add new items. But when i change to relative path, at runtime everything works just fine and everything but when i close the program everything that i have changed or added have been disposed and when i open it again nothing have been saved. This is how the relative path looks like

```
SqlConnection SQLCN = new SqlConnection
(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Databas\TestDatabase.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Any idea why it does like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you override the database on each build.

Probably you have the `Build Action` set to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy If Newer`.

From @steve's [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx), regarding the `Copy if newer` value:

*We don’t recommend this option for .mdb or .mdf files. The database file can change even when no changes are made to the data. Simply opening a connection on a data file (for example, by expanding the Tables node in Server Explorer) can mark it as newer.*